# WordPress terms loop with foreach and WP_Qurey as a nested loop issue

Tags: wordpress

I have create a custom post type for FAQs and Custom taxonomies to organize the Question & Answers.

Also I have create a single page template to display my FAQs by using the code that following

```
$terms = get_terms(
    'faq_categories',
    array(
        'orderby'   =>  'name',
        'order'     =>  'ASC'
    )
);

foreach($terms as $term)
{
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
    <?php

    $q_args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'faq',
        'tax_query'         =>  array(
            'taxonomy'  =>  'faq_categories',
            'field'     =>  'slug',
            'terms'     =>  $term->slug
        ),
        'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
    );

    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();

    $ans    =   new WP_Query($q_args);

    while($ans->have_posts())
    {
        $ans->the_post();

        ?>
        <h5><?php echo the_title(); ?></h5>
        <?php
    }
}
```

My problem is that while I get the question titles, the questions are not grouped by FAQ Categories and under each Category I get all the available questions in repeat.

The result looks like:

```
Sale [FAQ Category]
    How to buy? [FAQ Question]
    What is the cost? [FAQ Question]
    How can I contact you? [FAQ Question]
    What is your address? [FAQ Question]
Contacts [FAQ Category]
    How to buy? [FAQ Question]
    What is the cost? [FAQ Question]
    How can I contact you? [FAQ Question]
    What is your address? [FAQ Question]
```

Also I have try with **wp_reset_postdate()** and **wp_reset_query()** before and after the WP_Query loop, and I have try to remove them too with no luck.

Any idea on how to solve that issue?

Kind regards
Merianos Nikos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tax_query accepts an array of arrays.

```
$q_args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'faq',
    'tax_query'         =>  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  =>  'faq_categories',
            'field'     =>  'slug',
            'terms'     =>  $term->slug
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page'    =>  -1
);
```

Or rewrite your query, you don't really need a tax_query:

```
$ans = new WP_Query("post_type=faq&faq_categories=$term->slug&posts_per_page=-1");
```